# How can I delete a row in SQLite Database Using ID in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, sqlite

I want a field to be deleted from the sqlite database table when user Long Presses it in the list shown and I don't know query for it i tried to implement a logic of my own this might look stupid to you but it was the best i could think of..

```
onLongPress={()=> {
        let n = item.ID.toString();
        Alert.alert(n)
        db.transaction(txn => {
          txn.executeSql(
            `SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY ID DESC`,
            [],
            (sqlTxn, res) => {
              console.log("Users retrieved successfully");
              let len = res.rows.length;
              setNumbers([])
      
              if (len > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                  let item = res.rows.item(i);
                  if(item.ID!==n){
                    results.push({ ID: item.ID, number: item.CnicNumbers });
                    setNumbers(results);
                  }
                }
                getData();
                console.log(results);
              }
            },
            error => {
              console.log("error on getting users " + error.message);
            },
          );
        });
      }}
```

Please tell me what is wrong with my code or suggest me another way of doing so.
Please Don't roast me I'm a rookie.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This snippet doesn't seem to contain anything about deleting a row, am I missing something?

Comment: ok so what im trying to do here for deleting an element is to save the id of the element to delete in n variable then read entire table and push the values into an array named results if id of the value is !== n and then save the new results array in database.

Comment: Have you looked up how to delete things in sql? `DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 'xyz'`. It's also a little less scary to soft delete things - add a "deleted" column to the table and then you can use `UPDATE table SET deleted = true WHERE id = 'xyz'` - then if you accidentally delete your whole table it's easy to undo.